# What's the proper way to set prefix of key in Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using Redis to store the captcha and mobile code temporarily. When I `set` captcha, I use:`Redis.set('captcha' + remoteIP, text);`

I can see the key is `captcha:127.0.0.1` in GUI manager. Redis recognized the `captcha` as prefix automatically. If I use `Redis.set('captcha:' + remoteIP, text)`, the `key` will be `captcha::127.0.0.1`.

But when I `set` the code by `Redis.set('code' + mobile, code);`, the actual `key` is `code1xxxxxxxxxx`, no prefix. I must use `Redis.set('code:' + mobile, code)` then it works.

I'm using latest `node_redis`client in Node.js 5.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `remoteIP` already contains a `:`.  Redis didn't recognize captcha was a prefix and add a colon, it was just told to use whatever the expression `'captcha' + remoteIP` evaluated to as a key, in this case that was `captcha:127.0.0.1`, since `remoteIP === ':127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Keep in mind that Redis do not know anything about prefixes. Its just feature of concrete GUI manager.